# Laravel 4 calling a function from a retrieved model

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, eloquent

In Laravel 4 I have created two DB tables: users and user_pending_updates

I have created a model called User. If i get a user model:

`$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();`

And I want to call a function in the model:

```
    public static function isPendingUser()
    {
        $update = DB::table('user_pending_updates')->where('user_id', UNKNOWN)->where('pending_update', 1)->first();

        if(count($update) > 0)
        {
            return $update;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

My question is, if I call the function like this:

`$user->isPendingUser();`

How do I capture the $user->id variable inside the function so I can add it where I indicated UNKNOWN?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You should check for `null` instead of using `count`. That will be faster. One-liner (after `$update = ...`): `return null === $update ? false : $update;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the static modifier and the user id will be `$this->id`.